# sudo apt-get update Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) [IP:]

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, apt

I am not a linux admin by no means and I cant seem to figure this one out.

So I am ultimately trying to perform an update but running into a

> "Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) [IP:]"

NOTE: This is a new install of linux and the `df -H` is written below.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             17G     0   17G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.4G  2.2M  3.4G   1% /run
/dev/sda3        11G  7.2G  2.3G  76% /
tmpfs            17G     0   17G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            17G     0   17G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda4       7.0G  6.9G     0 100% /var
/dev/loop1      105M  105M     0 100% /snap/core/11743
/dev/sda2       270G  1.2G  255G   1% /home
/dev/sda1       2.0G  326M  1.6G  18% /boot
/dev/sda6       252M  5.5M  247M   3% /boot/efi
tmpfs           3.4G  173k  3.4G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop3      105M  105M     0 100% /snap/core/11798
```

I have performed `sudo apt-get autoclean /` clean and have used `bleachbit`.

Although I do not fully comprehend what these files are I have used disk analyzer and have found that the following file paths are full or nearing at capacity for memory:

```
# (I believe this may be the culprit but not 100%) is there  anyway
# to increase this folder? Seems small.
/var/lib/flatpak/repo/objects

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri 

 # is this typical to max out of memory?
 # Do I need to make adjustments to my network?
/usr/lib/modules/5.11.0-37-generic/kernal/drivers/net/ethernet/mellanox/mix5/core/mix5_cor.ko
```

Here is the lnode output for reference:

```
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            4096256    669  4095587    1% /dev
tmpfs           4107845   1191  4106654    1% /run
/dev/sda3        625856 333836   292020   54% /
tmpfs           4107845      1  4107844    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           4107845      2  4107843    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           4107845     18  4107827    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda4        438048 124688   313360   29% /var
/dev/loop1        12844  12844        0  100% /snap/core/11743
/dev/sda2      16785408  15314 16770094    1% /home
/dev/sda1        124928    316   124612    1% /boot
/dev/sda6             0      0        0     - /boot/efi
tmpfs           4107845    151  4107694    1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop3        12845  12845        0  100% /snap/core/11798
```

Is there something I am not seeing? I am unable to update or install anything currently because of this issue.
What can I do to fix these space issues?

UPDATE: So this just happened when I tried to reboot my machine let me know if this is clear. I am unable to get to terminal. It does not respond to my key commands.
[image: boot message]

Comment: Can you download other apps?

Comment: @AkshajSingla I can download no problem since it goes to my downloads folder but I am unable to install anything even though I still have 200 GB of memory.

Comment: Umm so probably you need to mess with partitions, currently @Garnet has posted an answer which tells you how to do it, If you have any other query then tell me I will try to solve it.

Comment: You probably corrupted a library when you ran out of space on your /var partition.  You will have to go to rescue/single user mode.  To find out which libraries are corrupted, make a note of which programs failed, i.e. "Thunderbolt, with the 'ldd' command.  Then reinstall the libraries the program uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your /dev/sda4, which mounts to /var, is full.  You can shrink one of your other partitions, i.e. /home (/dev/sda2) which has 255 G free with parted.  Then assign the freed up disk space to the /var partition.

Comment: Do you have documentation on hand to modify partitions?

Comment: You can get parted at [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/).  A search [link](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=change+parttion+size+with+parted&t=ffsb&ia=web) will bring up several tutorials for various experience levels.